# DynamoDB Burst Capacity and Adaptive Scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I was going over the AWS [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/) and from there the [AWS re:Invent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kMY0_m29YzU) to understand DynamoDB's concept of adaptive scaling and bursts. I understand the concept of WCU and RCU and the idea of burst buckets piling up to a period of 300 seconds and that the peak WCU/RCU of a partition is 1000/3000.

Starting time instant 23:00 of the video:

(1) The video gives an example of a table provisioned with 500 WCUs and 1500 RCUs. The table has 1 partition. The burst bucket after 5 minutes of "assumed" inactivity becomes 500*300=150K WCUs and 1500*300= 450K RCUs. And from there it is concluded that this table now with this burst bucket ready can offer **up to 5 minutes of sustained 1K WCU or 3K RCU** with one partition

**How are we arriving at this figure of "up to 5 minutes of sustained 1K WCU or 3K RCU"**? *In my understanding this should have been the calculation for RCU: 450K/3K=150 seconds*

(2) Further down, after the table splits into two partitions with the **provisioned** WCU/RCU getting evenly divided among the 2 partitions @250/750 respectively. With 2 partitions, the peak RCU doubles to 6K and peak WCU doubles to 2K and therefore they conclude that the same burst bucket now offers **up to 100 seconds of sustained 2K WCU or 6K RCU** with two partitions.

**How are we arriving at this figure of "up to 100 seconds of sustained 2K WCU or 6K RCU"**? *In my understanding this should have been the calculation for RCU: 450K/6K=75 seconds*

Any DynamoDB experts who could help derive this figure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> up to 5 minutes of sustained 1K WCU or 3K RCU

The table can *already* sustain 500 WCU and 1500 RCU *from its provisioned capacity alone*. Only usage in excess of the table's provisioned capacity is consuming burst capacity.  The table can sustain 500 WCU from provisioned + 500 WCU from burst = 1K WCU, for 300 seconds.

In the second scenario, the issue is the same.  You're calculating 450000 ÷ 6000 but should be calculating 450000 ÷ (6000 - 1500) = 100 seconds, because burst capacity is consumed only at the rate of overage.

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever you're not fully using a partition's throughput, DynamoDB reserves a portion of that unused capacity for later bursts of throughput to handle usage spikes.

> DynamoDB currently retains up to 5 minutes (300 seconds) of unused read and write capacity.

> Note that these burst capacity details might change in the future.

from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-throughput-bursting

By way of an example, say I provision a minimal DDB with 1RCU.

The max capacity in my RCU bucket is 300 RCU-seconds. We know 1 RCU is equivalent of 2 reads of 4KB/s. Multiplying that by seconds means an RCU-second is actually 2 reads of 4KB.

We can use those 300 tokens (RCU-s) to read at the maximum speed allowed by our table and our partitions, 600 of 4KB items, 60 of 40KB item, 6 of 400KB items, or anything in between.

Amazon describe replenishment as a "portion" of unused capacity but it is really *any* "unused read and write capacity". Rick Houlihan says as much in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kMY0_m29YzU, to paraphrase, "if this table sat there unused for 5 minutes it would end up with 450k RCUs and 150k WCUs". In the tiny table I have illustrated, that is 1 RCU-s for every second it is idle.

Answer (score -1):

#### (Total unused WCU/RCU saved for 5 minutes) / ((sustained WCU/RCU * number of partitions) - provisioned WCU/RCU )

### Single Partition:

WCU: 15000/ ((1000*1) - 500) = 300 seconds

RCU: 45000/ ((3000*1) - 1500) = 300 seconds

### Double Partion:

WCU : 15000 / ((1000*2) - 500) = 100 seconds

RCU : 45000 / ((3000 * 2) - 1500) = 100 seconds